# "index_already_exists_exception" - kafka to Elastic Search(SSL)

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We've kafka elastic search sink connector transporting data to Elastic search(v**5.6.3**).

I'm using confluent v5.0.0 and I do not see any other error. I've deleted the index and restarted the elastic search connector. But still getting same error

The connector configuration is as follows :

```
{
"name":"elasticsearch_topic",
"config":
{       
    "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max":"3",
    "topics":"sample_topic",
    "connection.url":"https://127.0.0.1:9200,https://127.0.0.2:9200",               
    "connection.username":"elsatic_user",
    "connection.password":"elastic_user",
    "type.name":"log",
    "flush.timeout.ms":"60000",
    "connection.timeout.ms":"60000",
    "read.timeout.ms":"60000",
    "batch.size":"20",
    "topic.index.map":"sample_topic:elastic_search_index_test",
    "transforms":"extract,insertenv,inserttimestamp,convert_current_ts,routeTS",
    "schema.ignore": "true",
    "transforms.extract.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
    "transforms.extract.field":"RE_NUM",
    "transforms.insertenv.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
        "transforms.insertenv.static.field": "_env",
        "transforms.insertenv.static.value": "dev",
        "transforms.inserttimestamp.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
        "transforms.inserttimestamp.timestamp.field": "date_time",      
            "transforms.convert_current_ts.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
        "transforms.convert_current_ts.target.type": "Timestamp",
        "transforms.convert_current_ts.field": "date_time",
        "transforms.convert_current_ts.format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS",
        "transforms.routeTS.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampRouter",  
    "transforms.routeTS.topic.format":"elastic_search_index_test-${timestamp}",  
    "transforms.routeTS.timestamp.format":"yyyyMMdd"
 }
}
```

So far so good. No issues.

Recently we've enabled SSL on elastic search and for this I've added "username" and "password" and "https" to the above configurations.Then restarted the connector and worker. 
Since then I can see "**index_already_exists_exception**" with error as below :

```
[2018-12-06 03:36:21,487] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=elasticsearch_topic-1} 
 Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception 
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:177)
 org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Could not create index 
 'elastic_search_index_test': {"root_cause": 
 [{"type":"index_already_exists_exception","reason":"index 
[elastic_search_index_test/QVgWV8E7RmuSArtIJt3m3g] already exists","index_uuid":"QVgWV8E7RmuSArtIJt3m3g","index":"elastic_search_index_test"}],"type":"index_already_exists_exception","reason":"index [elastic_search_index_test/QVgWV8E7RmuSArtIJt3m3g] already exists","index_uuid":"QVgWV8E7RmuSArtIJt3m3g","index":"elastic_search_index_test"}
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.jest.JestElasticsearchClient.createIndices(JestElasticsearchClient.java:238)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchWriter.createIndicesForTopics(ElasticsearchWriter.java:330)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.open(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:157)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.openPartitions(WorkerSinkTask.java:612)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.access$1100(WorkerSinkTask.java:69)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask$HandleRebalance.onPartitionsAssigned(WorkerSinkTask.java:672)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:283)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:422)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:352)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:337)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:343)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1218)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1181)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1115)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.pollConsumer(WorkerSinkTask.java:444)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:225)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:193)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 [2018-12-06 03:36:21,487] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=elasticsearch_topic-1} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:178)
```

**Steps that I've tried so far :**

1. Stopped the elastic search sink connector and worker
2. Deleted the index "elastic_search_index_test" from elastic search (through Kibana)
3. Restarted the worker and elastic search connector

But still getting the same error (as described above)

Could any one suggest what's wrong going on?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I'm using Kibana "Dev Tools" functionality to delete the indices like below : DELETE /elastic_search_index_test?pretty

Comment: @cricket_007 when you say "manual curl -XDELETE", can you elaborate that? I mean should I need to use some client like "postman" or something else?

Comment: Just something other than Kibana to isolate the issue. Connect clearly thinks an index exists, and is using standard HTTP, so Kibana doesn't really need to be part of the problem diagnosis

Comment: @cricket_007 `curl -XDELETE` also resulted in same error. ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=elasticsearch_topic-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:177)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Could not create index 'elastic_search_index_test': {"root_cause":[{"type":"index_already_exists_exception","reason":"index [elastic_search_index_test/RxUwoqpYQf-DqNJfJf6gAQ] already exists","index_uuid":"RxUwoqpYQf-DqNJfJf6gAQ"

Comment: I forgot to ask what version of Confluent Platform you're running. But I'm not sure here... I've not used SSL with Elasticsearch before, but I would think it would have some other errors, not saying it already exists.

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm using confluent v5.0.0 and I do not see any other error. I've deleted the index and restarted the elastic search connector. But still getting same error.

Comment: Can you remove `topic.index.map`? That option is listed as deprecated in the documentation

Comment: And can you show your data from console consumer? What is `RE_NUM` and does it look like `QVgWV8E7RmuSArtIJt3m3g`? I think the error is saying your document id's are colliding and you're not letting connect write as `topic+offset+partition`

Comment: @cricket_007 Even after removing the `topic.index.map`, same error is surfacing. And `RE_NUM` is being considered as key(VARCHAR in DB) that I'm extracting from incoming data

Comment: As I've described above, before ES was enabled with SSL, the es connector was working properly. But after enabling SSL, I'm seeing this behavior.

Comment: 1) *I would think it would have some other errors, not saying it already exists* -- Meaning I would expect **SSL errors** after setup, such as "unauthorized". 2) I think the problem is the key, not the index. How about if you add `"key.ignore": "true"`, or remove the transform on `RE_NUM`? According to the error, `QVgWV8E7RmuSArtIJt3m3g` is what **already exists** inside of `elastic_search_index_test`. At least, that is how I read it.

Answer (score 1):

This is very common error when you start connector with multiple tasks ("tasks.max":"3" in current case) .

Internal Steps kafka-connect-elasticsearch

1. kafka-connect-elasticsearch will be check if indexe does not exist
2. it will create index if missing in ES

Problem :-

this conector is running with 3 tasks (means 3 threads executing same code) and more than one task found that index does not exist and went on to create the index.
1st task succeed and 2nd will throw index not found exception because it was already created by 1st task.

Solution :-

1. start connector with one task "tasks.max":"1" (This is bad option if we have huge data)
2. create index in Es before running connector
3. use distributed lock (like zookeeper)

Comment: Let me try. But I still wonder why the elastic search connector didn't failed in the first place when there was no SSL enabled on the Elastic Search ? The issue surfaced only when the SSL enabled on the Elastic Search server.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. But I just tries by providing the admin credentials in my elastic search properties file and able to see the data flowing from kafka topic to elastic search cluster.